# How to properly initialize subclasses in Objective C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, initialization

I have two UIViews. They both require custom initialization, and it seems repetitive and bug-prone to simply copy initialization code in both initWithFrame: and initWithCoder:. However, having a standard initialization method name like initMyStuff results in the child's version being called twice. I could resolve this by giving each class a unique initialization name like initStuffForCustomViewParent, but I would prefer if there was a way to maintain a standard custom initialization method name in order to make my code more readable. Here is a sample implementation of the problem:

```
@implementation CustomViewParent
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    if(self=[super initWithFrame:aRect])
        [self initMyStuff];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
        [self initMyStuff];
    return self;
}

-(void)initMyStuff
{
    // Do stuff (never called)
}
@end

@implementation CustomViewChild
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect
{
    if(self=[super initWithFrame:aRect])
        [self initMyStuff];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])
        [self initMyStuff];
    return self;
}

-(void)initMyStuff
{
    // Do stuff (called twice)
}
@end

// SAMPLE
// Calls CustomViewChild's initMyStuff twice and CustomViewParent's initMyStuff never
CustomViewChild *obj = [[CustomViewChild alloc] init];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`CustomViewChild` shouldn't call `initMyStuff`. Just call this in the parent and the child's `initMyStuff` should call `[super initMyStuff]`.

But in either case, don't call it `initMyStuff` because that suggests it's an `init` method, which implies certain behaviors. Call it something like `setup` (assuming the goal is to have it called from both `initWithFrame` and `initWithCoder:`).

Comment: If the parent class was an NSObject, would there be any problems by having the parent class do this: if(self = [super init]) instead of if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder])? This would call the default init methods then go back down the chain and set the decoded variables.

Comment: If the parent class were an immediate subclass of NSObject, you would *have* to do it that way. NSObject doesn't implement <NSCoding>.